# OOP PHP - Get vars from one class and into a class within another file

Tags: php, class, oop

I have a situation where I'm creating a controller file that echo's json output to be used client-side with ajax:
`echo json_encode($response);`

The main class in another file, among other things, grabs all the setting vars from the CMS.

Now, the controller file has a class that generates the request from the API, but the setting vars in the class `(username, id, count, etc.)` are hard coded because I can't figure out how exactly to get them from the main class in the other file. With the settings hard coded, the controller file creates and echos the json output as expected. It just needs the dynamic vars from the main class.

Please excuse my lack of knowledge and usage of OOP. I've been trying it with a structure like this, where again, just trying to get the username and other vars from the main class into another class within separate file.

** **EDIT** ** Rethinking this a bit based on the comment by [@Dave Just](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1208233/dave-just) as it makes better sense. So if I move the api_request function into mainClass and `return` the response, I can get the variables I need and the request still works. So that would lead me to ask - how can I still echo the `$response` from the api_request function in a separate file? That separate file with the json is what I'm using for my ajax script.

```
class mainClass {
    public $username;

    function __construct() {
        ...
    }

    public function api_settings( $username ) {
        ...
    }
}

$main_class = new mainClass;
$main_class->api_settings();
// OR
$main_class->username;
```

**api-call.php**

```
class apiCall extends mainClass {

    public $username;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct;
        ...
    }

    public function api_request() {
        ...

        $return = $api_auth->request(
            'GET',
            $api_auth->url( '/cms-plug' ),
            array(
                //where I need to be able to grab the $username from the main class
                'username' => 'joebob' 
            )
        );

        echo json_encode($response);
    }

}

$api_class = new apiCall;
```

Comment: Bottom line: You're breaking the `SRP` and `LSP`

Comment: And `api_request()` should do binding not sending (don't echo it, but return) as it causes the method to do 2 things at once, which is kinda bad practice.

Comment: That makes perfect sense @DaveJust. See my edit above as it may be easier and better practice to handle with the new question ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked me to point out this,

There are so many flaws in your architecture

**First**,

When you do it like,

`class apiCall extends mainClass {`

you break the **Single Responsibility Principle** and **Liskov Substitution principle** at the same time

**Second**,

A controller should **never** echo anything

MVC itself looks like

```
$modelLayer = new ModelLayer();

$view = new View($modelLayer);

$controller = new Controller($modelLayer);
$controller->indexAction($request);

echo $view->render();
```

You actually implementing something that is close to **Model-View-Presenter**, not **MVC**

**Third**

Since your class starts from `api..` then there's no need to include that name in methods.

**Fourth**,

You don't have to tightly couple `json_encode()` with generation logic. That method should only return an array, then you'd `json_encode()` that array. Benefits? 1) Separation of Concerns 2) You can event convert that array to `YAML` or `XML`, not only `JSON`

And also, you should avoid inheritance in your case. Write singular class that deals with ApiCalls. So, it would look like as,

```
final class ApiCall
{

    /**
     * I'd use a name that makes sense
     * 
     * @param string $username
     * @return array on success, FALSE on failure
     */
    public function fetchByUsername($username)
    {

        $return = $api_auth->request(
            'GET',
            $api_auth->url( '/cms-plug' ),
            array('username' => $username)
        );

        if ($response !== false){

          return $response;

        } else {

          return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And you would use it like,

```
if (isset($_GET['username'])){

  $api = new ApiCall();

  $result = $api->fetchByUsername($_GET['username']);

  if ($result !== false){

     // Respond as JSON
     die(json_encode($result));

  } else {

    die('Wrong username');

  }
}
```

Comment: Using your examples, rebuilt it and everything is working as expected! Really appreciate you taking the time to write this out and point out the flaws. Still have much to learn.

Comment: @RyanPalmer There are good tutorials for beginners : `www.phpmaster.com`

Answer (score 1):

You can access properties from the current object with `this`. This also works for inherited properties from parent classes.

**api-call.php**

```
class apiCall extends mainClass {
    //public $username; // you don't have to decalre $username again, it gets already inherited from mainClass since its public there
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct;
        ...
    }

    public function api_request() {
        ...
        $return = $api_auth->request(
            'GET',
            $api_auth->url( '/cms-plug' ),
            array(
                //where I need to be able to grab the $username from the main class
                'username' => this->username // vars of the current object and inherited vars are available with "this" 
            )
        );
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
$api_class = new apiCall;
```